# Firebase Messaging: Send message to all devices

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've been trying to send a message to all devices using a topic named "all" - but it doesn't seem to work (details below in **The Problem**).

### Recieving Messages

I made every device subscribe to the "all" topic through my`FirebaseMessagingService` class, which is started once the user is authenticated:

```
// Inside of MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("all");
}

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    Log.d("FirebaseMessaging", "Got notification"); // This doesn't show up
    // Therefore the messages are not reaching the client
    ...
}
```

### Sending Messages

In order to send a message, the client pushes the data into the realtime database at `/messages/`. A cloud function is triggered and (supposedly) sends the message to "all" clients.

```
// This part works well, as I can see the realtime database directly
final DatabaseReference ref = db.getReference().child("messages");
HashMap hashMap = new HashMap();
hashMap.put(alert.getGroup() + " " + auth.getCurrentUser().getUid() + " " + (new Date()).getTime(), alert);
ref.setValue(hashMap);
```

And here's the cloud function:

```
exports.sendMessage = functions.database.ref("/messages/{meta}")
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
        const message = snapshot._data;
        console.log("msg", message["title"], message["description"], message["user"], message["group"]);
        if(message["event"] === "new message") {
            const payload = {
                data: message
                },
                topic: message["group"]
            }

            admin.database().ref("/messages/" + context.params.meta).remove()
            return admin.messaging().sendToTopic("all", payload)
        }
        return false
    });
```

### The Problem

Here's the list of events that I observe: 
1. The clients sends the message 
2. The realtime database is updated (I can see it directly) 
3. The cloud function is triggered (I can see the `console.log`) 
And... here it stops. `onMessageReceived` is never triggered. I have no idea why that would be. 
Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: have to run any demo before?   and have you entered intent filters in manifest file

Comment: @Rohit What do you mean by a demo? And yes, I have the intent filters with the MESSAGING_EVENT action that the service requires. I should note that it all works if I send a notification with the available GUI.

Comment: As per my understanding, you are mixing firebase database with firebase notification, Notification will work differently and firebase database differently

Comment: When modification in database your onDataChanged method will call

Comment: When you receive a notification from web then your onMessageReceived method will trigger

Comment: @Rohit Well, the problem is that it doesn't. The message doesn't arrive at the client. That is either because 1. I did not subscribe correctly or 2. I am not sending the message correctly. I am trying to figure out which one it is.

Comment: As per my observation your push notification function is not calling properly from webend and that push notification have a specific structure of message as per following 
link https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options

Comment: @Rohit It seems that I am following the correct structure of a data message - data and a topic (like https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging). It also seems that I am sending the message correctly, so the only thing that remains is the way I subscribed to the topic.